# Abrir site do perfil dos membros em outra aba

Tags: novo-recurso, perfil

Olá,

Dentro do perfil da rede dos membros, podemos colocar nosso site pessoal e quando clicamos neste link o site poderia abrir em uma aba externa e não na mesma página do site em que estamos.

Creio que ficaria melhor assim.

Comment: Tem várias coisas que deveriam abrir numa aba a parte e não na atual. De qualquer formar eu duvido muito que isso será feito, seria uma boa a gente fazer um plugin pra isso.

Comment: Relacionada: [Tem como manter a aba “Participação” fixa quando entro no perfil dos usuários?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4143/3117)